# Using Facebook Audience Network SDK to serve ads in app

Tags: facebook, ads, facebook-audience-network

I want to serve ads in my game im making using the Facebook Audience Network in this page it says "we will not serve ads to users that have advertising opt-outs enabled in their iOS & Android devices" does this mean no facebook ads will show at all in my app or just not targeted ads ?https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/faq#

Comment: My reading of that is "no Facebook ads at all".

Comment: how is it possible though to opt out of seeing facebook ads through our iphone & android? I didn't even know this was possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Previously I wrote that ads will show for non Facebook users but that is wrong. Ads will **only** show for users which has the native Facebook app installed on their devices. I'm sorry if I mislead you.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? Thanks!